# Cocoa: getting information and playing a mp3

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's the easiest way to:

1. load an mp3 from filesystem
2. get a mp3 bitrate metadata
3. mp3 file size
4. play the mp3 on iTunes

with Cocoa ?

I currently have the file path only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For metadata you can use [MDItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html).

> MDItem is a CF-compliant object that represents a file and the
>   metadata associated with the file.

```
MDItemRef metadata = MDItemCreate(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"/Users/parag/0.mp3");
NSNumber *audioBitrate = (NSNumber *)MDItemCopyAttribute(metadata, kMDItemAudioBitRate); 
NSLog(@"audioBitrate:%i", [audioBitrate intValue]);
```

For file size

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/Users/parag/0.mp3" error:nil] fileSize];
```

play the mp3 on iTunes

```
NSString *cmd = @"open -a /Applications/iTunes.app '/Users/parag/0.mp3'";
system([cmd UTF8String]);
```